# "foreach" parallel loop returns <NA>s

Tags: r, foreach, dataframe

I am trying to process several list items in parallel.

My goal is to: run some labeling function on every column, based on its values. Then return dataframe with the node name, column name, and the processed label

The workflow works fine using a normal for loop. However, when I try to do the same thing in a foreach loop, the results returned are 
(Please note: the following is just an abstraction of the original dataset)

I am not sure what exactly is getting messed up in between.. If you can help me to sort that thing out that would be awesome :-)

```
set.seed(12345)
options(stringsAsFactors = F)


# I. Random data generation (Original data is in data frame format)
random.data = list()
random.data[["one"]] = as.data.frame(matrix(data = runif(n = 15), ncol = 3))
random.data[["two"]] = as.data.frame(matrix(data = runif(n = 15), ncol = 3))
random.data[["three"]] = as.data.frame(matrix(data = runif(n = 15), ncol = 3))



# II. Some function applied to each column to label/classify the values
valslabel = function(DataCOlumn) {
  if(mean(DataCOlumn) < 0.5) return("low")
  return("high")
}



# III. Generating the desired output in a regular for loop : 

desiredOutput = list()

for(frame.i in seq_along(random.data)) {

  frame = random.data[[frame.i]]
  frame.name = names(random.data)[frame.i]
  frame.results = data.frame(frame.name = character(0), 
                  mappedField = character(0), label = character(0) )

  for(col.i in 1:ncol(frame)) {
    frame.results[col.i, "frame.name"] = frame.name
    frame.results[col.i, "mappedField"] = colnames(frame)[col.i]
    frame.results[col.i, "label"] = valslabel(frame[,col.i])  
  }

  desiredOutput[[frame.name]] = frame.results
}


print(desiredOutput)

# $one
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1        one          V1  high
# 2        one          V2  high
# 3        one          V3   low
# 
# $two
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1        two          V1   low
# 2        two          V2  high
# 3        two          V3   low
# 
# $three
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1      three          V1   low
# 2      three          V2  high
# 3      three          V3  high




# IV. Using the "foreach" parallel execution

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl = makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)

output = foreach(frame.i = seq_along(random.data), .verbose = T) %dopar% {

  frame = random.data[[frame.i]]
  frame.name = names(random.data)[frame.i]
  frame.results = data.frame(frame.name = character(0), mappedField = character(0), label = character(0) )

  for(col.i in 1:ncol(frame)) {
    frame.results[col.i, "frame.name"] = frame.name
    frame.results[col.i, "mappedField"] = colnames(frame)[col.i]
    frame.results[col.i, "label"] = valslabel(frame[,col.i])  
  }

  return(frame.results)
}


print(output)

# [[1]]
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 2       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 3       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#   
# [[2]]
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 2       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 3       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#   
# [[3]]
# frame.name mappedField label
# 1       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 2       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
# 3       <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the way you initialise your data frame, and the fact that within the `foreach` environment, the option `stringsAsFactors` is not set to `FALSE`. What is happening in each `foreach` loop is something like this

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d <- data.frame(x =character(0))
d[1, "x"] <- "a"
#Warning message:
#In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "a") :
#  invalid factor level, NA generated
d
#     x
#1 <NA>
```

Note that this only gives a warning, and not an error so the loop doesn't stop. If you set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` first there is no problem (as you did when not running stuff in parallel)

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d <- data.frame(x =character(0))
d[1, "x"] <- "a"
d
#  x
#1 a
```

In your global environment you already set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` so the `%do%` loop worked. However this option does not get passed in the local environment of each parallel job and so the `%dopar%` loop runs into the problem above.

Look for example at the output of the following

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
.Options$stringsAsFactors
#[1] FALSE
foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% .Options$stringsAsFactors
#[[1]]
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[2]]
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[3]]
#[1] TRUE
```

So the solution is to set the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside the `foreach` loop.

As an aside, it is much better to create your data frame using the whole column vector rather than row-by-row when possible. In your example you can replace

```
frame.results = data.frame(frame.name = character(0), mappedField = character(0), label = character(0))
for(col.i in 1:ncol(frame)) {
    frame.results[col.i, "frame.name"] = frame.name
    frame.results[col.i, "mappedField"] = colnames(frame)[col.i]
    frame.results[col.i, "label"] = valslabel(frame[,col.i])  
}
```

with

```
frame.results <- data.frame( 
    frame.name = frame.name, 
    mappedField = colnames(frame), 
    label = valslabel1(colMeans(frame)))
```

where the `valslabel` function has been replaced by a vectorised version

```
valslabel1 <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x < 0.5, "low", "high")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konvas. Very very well caught !!

Comment: @Deena @cryo111 By the way I noticed that if you register the parallel back end by using the argument `cores`, ie `registerDoParallel(cores = 6)` the option _is_ passed to the local environment of each job... Not sure why this is and whether it is platform specific

Comment: @konvas That's funny. I checked it on my Linux Mint 17.1 machine and it is like you said, `registerDoParallel(cores = 6)` makes the `stringsAsFactors` option set to `FALSE` for all processes.

Comment: @konvas Just checked the `registerDoParallel` source code. The difference for non-Windows OSs seems to be that with `missing(cl)==TRUE`, `setDoPar(doParallelMC, cores, mcinfo)` gets called whereas with `missing(cl)==FALSE` the line `setDoPar(doParallelSNOW, cl, snowinfo)` gets executed. So it seems as if `doParallelMC` exports the options and `doParallelSNOW` does not.